# Unable to change passed arguments to rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I specify the value for argument, it is a string. So I tried to turn it into an integer, but this is not working.

Code is like this:

```
task :fetch_video, [:fetch_number] => :environment do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:fetch_number => 4)
  args.fetch_number = args.fetch_number.to_i
  puts args.fetch_number.class

  #run rake fetch_video[10]，
  #returns: String
end
```

What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write the `args` variable, I don't think you can do that. Try this:

```
task :fetch_video, [:fetch_number] => :environment do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:fetch_number => 4)
  local_fetch_number = args.fetch_number.to_i
  puts local_fetch_number.class
end
```

Comment: Additional question, How can I specify the input as a integer? I think this will solve my problem as well. `[10]` is considered as a string.

Comment: I don't think you can since it's coming from the command line.